# Where does the pointer to string stored

Tags: c

```
void main()
{
    char *p = "hello";
}
```

What is the storage type of P and where points in memory(stack/data segment)?
Where the string "helllo" stored?

Comment: For example, under gcc+linux environment, "hello" is in the `.rodata` segment.

Answer (score 5):

p is a local variable and typically resides on the stack.

The string is stored wherever the compiler decides to store it. Typically it will be in neither stack nor heap but rather in a read only area of the data segment of the executable image.

Answer (score 2):

The string is stored in read-only memory. The pointer itself is stored on the stack of `main`.

Comment: Architectures that don't have read-only memory cannot have C compilers made for them? :-)

Answer (score 2):

Unless your compiler documentation *explicitly* says that `void main()` is a legal signature, use `int main(void)` instead:

```
int main(void)
{
  char *p = "hello";
  return 0;
}
```

Exactly where the memory for `p` and the string `"hello"` are allocated will vary with the implementation.  For both ELF and PE/COFF formats, the memory for `p` will be inside of the stack frame for `main` and the memory for `"hello"` will be in a read-only data segment (`.rdata` for PE/COFF, `.rodata` for ELF).

Answer (score 0):

Your string sotred in the memory, and the pointer refer to the memory address wehere the string is stored. If you call this pointer it's return whit the memory address, and you can use this.

Comment: Doesn't answer the OP's question.